# Can't GET user Data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I'm trying to Get user info after a google login, i'm using passportjs, the code is working well, after the code runs I get the user data on *localhost:4000/login/success* as shown in the image below
[image]

But I cant fetch the data from it to show in the frontend

I'm trying this code:

```
  const googleSignIn = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_START" });
    window.open("http://localhost:4000/auth/google/callback", "_self");
    const result = await axios.get(
      "http://localhost:4000/login/success",
      console.log("THE INFO IS " + result)
    );
    if (result) {
      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: result.data });
    }
  };
```

Comment: what was the error you are gettting ?

Comment: The problem is that I'm not getting an error! I'm not getting anything in console!

Answer (score 0):

Because You are console logging the data in the second param of the get request. The Second Param is the body of the request.

Instead console.log like..

```
const result = await axios.get(
      "http://localhost:4000/login/success"
    );
  
console.log("THE INFO IS " + result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = await axios.get(
   "http://localhost:4000/login/success"
);
  
console.log("THE INFO IS " + result)
```